# Getting connection timeout error while calling get access token Microsoft Graph API through REST POST call

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to get access token from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentname}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenentname%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) endpoints though HttpClient post request. Applied required 4 parameters/headers with the same.
But I am getting connection timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address (after trying with 7 different IP address) getting Shutdown connection error. Connection discarded.

Please find below code snippet.

```
HttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();    
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentname}/oauth2/v2.0/token"); 
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", {id_value}));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", {secret_value}));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ClosableHttpClinet httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager).build();
ClosableHttpResponse response = httpClinet.execute(post);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Same its worked with Postman without any proxy setting, I am getting proper response in Postman.
Please assist on the same.

Comment: Instead of using HTTPClient, i tried with Microsoft Graph Client (you can download from NuGet) and it worked for me. So i would suggest you to follow the steps. (1) [Install the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) (2) [Configure the GraphClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS) (3) [Make the call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS). Hope this helps you moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please tell me what will be dependency for ivy as we are using ivy.xml not maven or gradle.

Comment: The closest one i can find is [this](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.microsoft.azure/spring-social-microsoft-graph/0.1.5/source-code/com/microsoft/azure/msgraph/api/Messages.java)

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Hi Dev, yes it worked thanks

Comment: Glad that it helped. Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting and accepting it as answer. So it will be useful to the others in the community as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HTTPClient, i tried with Microsoft Graph Client (you can download from NuGet) and it worked for me. So i would suggest you to follow the steps.

- [Install the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation)
- [Configure the GraphClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS)
- [Make the call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS).

Also with specific to ivy dependency, here's the [related thread](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.microsoft.azure/spring-social-microsoft-graph/0.1.5/source-code/com/microsoft/azure/msgraph/api/Messages.java).

Comment: Thanks Dev. Which jar it required like we have Microsoft graph Auth, Core or Beta. Could you please tell me the specific jar and its version as I am not getting the ClientCredentialProvider and IGraphServiceClient from microsoft-graph-2.4.0.jar.